# Is there a way to suport 0x0 Matrix on Math.Net?

Tags: c#, math.net

I'm using a `Matrix` `Nx2` to store a list of `Point`s that form a polygonal.

I have a function that return a submatrix `Nx2` containing points that are above a line with a simple equation, `y = 6`, for example.

The problem is sometimes the submatrix does not have points.

Then I want to do something like:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
double[,] pontos = { { }, { } };
Matrix mat = DenseMatrix.OfArray(pontos);
```

Is there a way to support `0x0` `Matrix` and have `Matrix.RowCount == 0`?

Comment: Sounds like an XY problem. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: That's not a `0x0` array, it's a `double[2,0]`.

Comment: Use `new double[0,0];` to declare a 0x0 array

Comment: Panagiotis, thanks for point this out. But my main problem is with null data.

Comment: @Sweeper, I had to research for XY problem, and then edit the post. English is not my first language. But I thing that now is more clear.

Comment: I still don't see the need for 0x0 matrix from the updated question. I would imagine any operation involving 0x0 matrix would not affect the other matrix ? The documentation mentions "Empty matrices or vectors are not supported, i.e. each dimension must have a length of at least 1." https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/Matrix.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is impossible. When creating any `Matrix` `MathNet` always comes to creating a `MatrixStorage` with constructor:

```
// MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Storage.MatrixStorage<T>
using MathNet.Numerics.Properties;
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

protected MatrixStorage(int rowCount, int columnCount)
{
    if (rowCount <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("rowCount", Resources.MatrixRowsMustBePositive);
    }
    if (columnCount <= 0)
    {
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("columnCount", Resources.MatrixColumnsMustBePositive);
    }
    RowCount = rowCount;
    ColumnCount = columnCount;
}
```

So as one can see no 0x0 `Matrix` is possible with `MathNet`.

**Update:**

You can do such a hack:

```
static class EmptyDenseMatrix
{
    public static DenseMatrix Create()
    {
        var storage = DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<double>.OfArray(new double[1, 1]);
        var type = typeof(DenseColumnMajorMatrixStorage<double>);
        type.GetField("RowCount").SetValue(storage, 0);
        type.GetField("ColumnCount").SetValue(storage, 0);
        type.GetField("Data").SetValue(storage, new double[0]);

        return new DenseMatrix(storage);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Console.WriteLine(EmptyDenseMatrix.Create());
```

Gives:

```
DenseMatrix 0x0-Double
```

But there is no meaningful thing you can do with such a matrix within `MathNet`, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(EmptyDenseMatrix.Create()* EmptyDenseMatrix.Create());
```

Gives:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The number of rows of a matrix must be positive.